# showing weather data using openweathermap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, weather-api, openweathermap

I have built a weather widget for my website using openweathermap. JS & html is --
JS-->

```
    $(function() {

        $('.weather-temperature').openWeather({
            city: 'Dhaka, BD',
            descriptionTarget: '.weather-description',
            windSpeedTarget: '.weather-wind-speed',
            minTemperatureTarget: '.weather-min-temperature',
            maxTemperatureTarget: '.weather-max-temperature',
            humidityTarget: '.weather-humidity',
            sunriseTarget: '.weather-sunrise',
            sunsetTarget: '.weather-sunset',
            placeTarget: '.weather-place',
            iconTarget: '.weather-icon',
            customIcons: 'images/icons/weather/',
            success: function() {

                //show weather
                $('.weather-wrapper').show();

            },
            error: function(message) {

                console.log(message);

            }
        });

    });
```

HTML -->/*

```
                                    <div class="weather-wrapper hide">
                <select id='list'>
                        <option value='1'>Dhaka</option>
                        <option value='2'>Pabna</option>
                </select>

                <img src="" class="weather-icon" alt="Weather Icon" />

                <p><strong>Place</strong>
                <br /><span class="weather-place"></span></p>

                <p><strong>Temperature</strong>
                <br /><span class="weather-temperature"></span> (<span class="weather-min-temperature"></span> - <span class="weather-max-temperature"></span>)</p>

                <p><strong>Description</strong>
                <br /><span class="weather-description capitalize"></span></p>

                <p><strong>Humidity</strong>
                <br /><span class="weather-humidity"></span></p>

                <p><strong>Wind speed</strong>
                <br /><span class="weather-wind-speed"></span></p>

                <p><strong>Sunrise</strong>
                <br /><span class="weather-sunrise"></span></p>

                <p><strong>Sunset</strong>
                <br /><span class="weather-sunset"></span></p>

            </div>      */
```

//

Without any 'select' option it working properly for 'Dhaka' city. I want to change city name using select option and show changed weather data. How it possible using jquery.change() . Plz help me out.

Comment: You need to trigger your js function on change/click of the select element, and pass the value of the selected option.

Comment: //I have done this but not working//

$('#list').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '1') {
        $('.weather-temperature').openWeather({
            city: 'Dhaka, BD',
           ................
            customIcons: 'images/icons/weather/',
            success: function() {

                //show weather
                $('.weather-wrapper').show();

            },
            error: function(message) {

                console.log(message);

            }
        });
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
HTML

```
<select id='list'>
                    <option value='Dhaka'>Dhaka</option>
                    <option value='Pabna'>Pabna</option>
            </select>
```

JS

```
 var loc;
 $('#list').change(function() {
 loc = $('#list').val();
   $('.weather-temperature').openWeather({
    city: "' + loc + '",
    //etc.
```

Comment: this code looking perfect. But Its not working. and its embrassing me, i dont have any idea why its not working. Have u another solution ?